# Not able to display line in D3 bar/line chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a combination bar and line graph. The bar is the primary y axis representing data.total and the line is the secondary y axis representing data.percent.

Disclaimer:I'm very new to javascript and D3.

I've been clunking away for hours trying to figure out why the chart won't render the line series. Some of this code was based upon other example templates I found online so there may be something in there that isn't kosher with my modifications and I completely missed it.

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<STYLE>`enter code here`
svg{ padding-left: 100 px}
path {
    stroke: Black;
    stroke-width: 1;
    fill: none;
}
 .chartTitle{ 
    color: #002b80;
    font-size: 32pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;

}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div class="chartTitle">Estimate of "Everything is Awesome"</div>
<SCRIPT SRC = 'd3.min.js'></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT>

var data =  [
    {'date': '4/1/2015', 'total':500, 'percent':0.535},
    {'date': '5/1/2015', 'total': 650, 'percent': 0.593},
    {'date': '6/1/2015', 'total': 700, 'percent': 0.687},
    {'date': '7/1/2015', 'total': 750, 'percent': 0.734},
    {'date': '8/1/2015', 'total': 800, 'percent': 0.988},
    {'date': '9/1/2015', 'total': 850, 'percent': 0.99},
    {'date': '10/1/2015', 'total': 900, 'percent': 1.0}
    ];

var margin = {top: 70, right: 70, bottom: 70, left:60},
    width = 600,
    height = 500;   


var toolTip = d3.select('body').append('div')
        .style('position', 'absolute')
        .style('background', 'white')
        .style('opacity', .9)
        .style('padding', '0 20px') 
        .style('border-radius', '25px')
        .style('border', ' 2px solid dodgerblue')

// X and Y Axis         
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(data[0].date), d3.time.month.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 0)])
    .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right ]);

var y1Scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total;})])
    .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

var y2Scale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.percent;})])
    .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(d3.time.month, 1)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b -%y'))
    .tickSize(1)
    .tickPadding(8);

var y1Axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y1Scale)
    .orient('left')
    .tickPadding(8)
    .tickSize(1);

var y2Axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y2Scale)
    .orient('right')
    .tickPadding(8)
    .tickSize(1);   

var lineData = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return -1 * y2Scale(d.percent); });

//Chart Body    
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');

//Chart Body Creation
svg.selectAll('.chart')
    .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .style('fill', 'dodgerblue')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('x', function(d) { return xScale(new Date(d.date)); })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - (height - margin.top - margin.bottom - y1Scale(d.total)) })
    .attr('width', 20)
    .attr('height', function(d) { return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - y1Scale(d.total) })
// Roll over SFX    
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
       toolTip.transition()
       .style('opacity', .9)
       toolTip.html(d.total)
         .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 40) + 'px')  
         .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px') 
       d3.select(this)
       .style('opacity', 0.5)
        })
    .on('mouseout', function (d) {
       toolTip.transition()
        .delay(100)
        .duration(600)
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .style('pointer-events', 'none')
       d3.select(this)
       .style('opacity', 1)
        });

//lDraw Line        
svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", lineData(data))
    .style('stroke', 'DarkOrange');

//Draw the X Axis
svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ')')
    .call(xAxis);
//Draw the Y1 Axis
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .call(y1Axis);

//Draw the Y2 Axis
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (height ) + " ,0)") 
  .call(y2Axis); 
   </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1:

You have date in this format `{'date': '10/1/2015', 'total': 900, 'percent': 1.0}` in your JSON, you will need to convert it into date object.

```
var format = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y");
data.forEach(function(d){
  d.date = format.parse(d.date);
});
```

For various date format parsing [refer](http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/ca0adb7e426c12c06a95)

Problem2:

You are defining the domain incorrectly

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(data[0].date), d3.time.month.offset(new Date(data[data.length - 1].date), 0)])
    .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right ]);
```

Domain should be min/max of the date.

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([d3.min(data, function(d){return d.date}), d3.max(data, function(d){return d.date})])
  .rangeRound([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
```

Reason for why is line not drawing up

```
var lineData = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })//this date is not in the correct format so d3 does not know what to do and so gives NaN.
    .y(function(d) { return -1 * y2Scale(d.percent); });
```

Now Problem 1 will fix this issue since we have converted the data into date.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/kwjppgmL/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked! I did find that I had to adjust the format variable to the following:

var format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");

data.forEach(function(d){
  d.date = format.parse(d.date);
});

when it was %d%m%Y it would register the month as the day and rendered everything as January in the x axis label.

You are a life saver. Thank you so much!